# Iphone Camera, Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: iphone, camera, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am creating a iPhone app using Titanium Appcelerator. For one of the tabs, I want to include a camera. When I click the camera image I want the app to:

- open the camera and take a picture
- ask if the user wants to take another picture
- then open the camera again is yes
- (loop)
- put the images (saved locally) into an array
- back button!

I can't seem to find the camera function anywhere.

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/questions/tag/camera

Answer (score 0):

This link gives a brief example but suggests looking at the kitchen sink demo app, kitchen sink has an example of just about everything.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/66021/api---camera

Answer (score 0):

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:"Using the Camera and Video",
    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:"Use camera",
    width:180,
    height:48,
    bottom: 12,
    zIndex:2
});

button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    //Open the photo gallery
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        //function to call upon successful load of the gallery
        success:function(e){
            if(e.mediaType === Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO){
                //e.media represents the photo or video
                var imageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                    image:e.media,
                    width:320,
                    height:480,
                    top:12,
                    zIndex:1
                });
                win.add(imageView);
            }else if(e.mediaType === Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){

                var w = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                    title:"New Video",
                    backgroundColor:"#000000"
                });

                var videoPlayer = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
                    media:e.media,
                    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF",
                    //movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
                    /*other values
                     * Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_EMBEDDED
                     * Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_FULLSCREEN
                     * Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_HIDDEN
                     * Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_NONE
                     */
                    //movieControlStyle:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_FULLSCREEN,
                    //scalingMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
                    /*other values
                     * Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FILL
                     * Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_FILL
                     * Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_NONE
                     */
                });

                w.add(videoPlayer);

                videoPlayer.addEventListener("complete", function(e){
                    w.remove(videoPlayer);
                    videoPlayer = null;
                    w.close();
                });

                w.open({modal:true});
            }

        },
        error:function(e){
            alert("There was an error");
        },
        cancel:function(e){
            alert("The event was cancelled");
        },
        //Allow editing of media before success
        allowEditing:true,
        saveToPhotoGallery:true,
        //Media types to allow
        mediaTypes:[Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO,Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO],
        //The other is Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
        //If recording video, you can set the quality to record at
        videoQuality:Titanium.Media.QUALITY_HIGH
        /*other possible values for this property are
         * Titanium.Media.QUALITY_MEDIUM
         * Titanium.Media.QUALITY_LOW
         */
    });
});

Titanium.App.addEventListener('camera_button', function(){
    Titanium.Media.takePicture();
});

win.add(button);

win.open();
```